# WEIGHT_PER_SECOND,^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `WEIGHT_PER_SECOND` in `weights::constants

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-parachain-template

I want to use `WEIGHT_PER_SECOND` in this code :

```
parameter_types! {
    pub const BlockHashCount: BlockNumber = 2400;
    pub const Version: RuntimeVersion = VERSION;
    /// We allow for 2 seconds of compute with a 6 second average block time.
    pub BlockWeights: frame_system::limits::BlockWeights = frame_system::limits::BlockWeights
        ::with_sensible_defaults(2 * WEIGHT_PER_SECOND, NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO);
    pub BlockLength: frame_system::limits::BlockLength = frame_system::limits::BlockLength
        ::max_with_normal_ratio(5 * 1024 * 1024, NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO);
    pub const SS58Prefix: u8 = 42;
}
```

and I use this code for import `WEIGHT_PER_SECOND` :

```
    pub use frame_support::{
    traits::{
        ConstU128, ConstU32, ConstU64, ConstBool,ConstU8, KeyOwnerProofSystem,Nothing, Randomness, StorageInfo,
    },
    weights::{
        constants::{BlockExecutionWeight, ExtrinsicBaseWeight, RocksDbWeight, WEIGHT_PER_SECOND},
    },
};
```

I used this part of code in previous versions of substrate but in this version I faced this problem.

**What's the problem, and how can I solve it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was renamed to `WEIGHT_REF_TIME_PER_SECOND` since with chromatic weights the weight has two components. *Ref time* and *Proof Size*.
There also is `WEIGHT_PROOF_SIZE_PER_MB` [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/d0540a79967cb06cd7598a4965c7c06afc788b0c/primitives/weights/src/lib.rs#L49).

Comment: it show me this error : `^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Weight`, found `u64``

Comment: You can construct a two-dimensional `Weight` with `Weight::from_parts` by passing in the ref-time and proof size. So for example `Weight::from_parts(2 * WEIGHT_REF_TIME_PER_SECOND, 5 * WEIGHT_PROOF_SIZE_PER_MB)`.